# python - Convert list of dicts to hierarchy/multiple nested dicts - issue with orders

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, parent-child

Currently I have these input:

```
query = [{'id': 1, 'desc': 'desc_father', 'parent_id': None}
         ,{'id': 2, 'desc': 'desc_child_1', 'parent_id': 10}
         ,{'id': 3, 'desc': 'desc_child_2', 'parent_id': 2}
         ,{'id': 4, 'desc': 'desc_child_5', 'parent_id': 5}
         ,{'id': 5, 'desc': 'desc_child_6', 'parent_id': 6}
         ,{'id': 6, 'desc': 'desc_child_1', 'parent_id': 1}]
```

This is my recursive function:

```
def recursive(parent_list, child_dict, parent_id):
    for l in parent_list:
        if parent_id in l.values():
            if 'children' not in l:
                l['children'] = []
            l['children'].append(child_dict)
            break
        else:
            for i in l:
                if isinstance(l[i], list):
                    recursive(d[i], child_dict, parent_id)
    return parent_list
```

This is my main code:

```
results = []
for q in query:
    dict_item = {}
    dict_item['id'] = q['id']
    dict_item['desc'] = q['desc']
    if q['parent_id'] is None:
        results.append(dict_item)
    else:
        results= recursive(results, dict_item, q['parent_id'])
return results
```

So, with above given data and the code, I have the result as below:

```
[{
        'desc' : 'desc_father',
        'id' : 1,
        'children' : [{
                'desc' : 'desc_child_1',
                'id' : 2,
                'children' : [{
                        'desc' : 'desc_child_2',
                        'id' : 3
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                'desc' : 'desc_child_1',
                'id' : 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This result is as you could see missing the items with `id = 4` and `id = 5` because during the loops, the parents of these items haven't been created yet (the items with `id = 5` & `id = 6`). I am having difficulties in fixing this problem as I don't know how to traverse back or forward the list to create the father item before the children ones. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

***UPDATED***

I have added in one case for my query, which is the item with `id = 2`, this time the item is updated its parent_id to 10 (`parent_id = 10`), since we do not have the item with `id = 10` as parent in our return result, so this `id = 2` item will also be a root.

My new code based on Scott Hunter guidance but I still could not make it to work. I must have misunderstood somewhere:

```
new_dict = {}
for q in query:
    q['Children'] = []
    new_dict[q['id']] = q

for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    print k, v
    if v['parent_id'] is not None and v['parent_id'] in new_dict:
        new_dict[k]['Children'].append(v)

print new_dict
```

***UPDATED-2***

Now I make it to work, based on Scott Hunter suggestion, please see my below code. However the code looks ugly with too many for, is there anyway that I could perfect this? Thanks a lot for your support, just one more step and it will be done!

```
new_dict = {}

for q in query:
    q['children'] = []
    q['parent'] = 1
    new_dict[q['id']] = q

for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    p_id = v['parent_id']
    for kk, vv in new_dict.iteritems():
        if kk == p_id:
            v['parent'] = 0
            vv['children'].append(v)

results = []

for d_id, d_item in new_dict.iteritems():
    if d_item['parent'] == 1:
        results.append(d_item)

print results
```

Comment: Why are you making `v` one of its own children?

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter , I have made it to work. Could you please review my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This would be my solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from pprint import pprint
query = [{'id': 1, 'desc': 'desc_father', 'parent_id': None}
         ,{'id': 2, 'desc': 'desc_child_1', 'parent_id': 1}
         ,{'id': 3, 'desc': 'desc_child_2', 'parent_id': 2}
         ,{'id': 4, 'desc': 'desc_child_5', 'parent_id': 5}
         ,{'id': 5, 'desc': 'desc_child_6', 'parent_id': 6}
         ,{'id': 6, 'desc': 'desc_child_1', 'parent_id': 1}]


def rec(query, parent):
    parent['children'] = []
    for item in query:
        if item['parent_id'] == parent['id']:
            parent['children'].append(item)
            rec(query, item)


root = {'id': None}
rec(query, root)

pprint(root, indent=4)
```

It gives me the output (The keys are out of order, but that's what you get when you use a dictionary)

```
maurice@ubuntu:~/Dev/random$ python recursion_tree.py 
{   'children': [   {   'children': [   {   'children': [],
                                            'desc': 'desc_child_2',
                                            'id': 3,
                                            'parent_id': 2}],
                        'desc': 'desc_child_1',
                        'id': 2,
                        'parent_id': 1},
                    {   'children': [   {   'children': [   {   'children': [   ],
                                                                'desc': 'desc_child_5',
                                                                'id': 4,
                                                                'parent_id': 5}],
                                            'desc': 'desc_child_6',
                                            'id': 5,
                                            'parent_id': 6}],
                        'desc': 'desc_child_1',
                        'id': 6,
                        'parent_id': 1}],
    'desc': 'desc_father',
    'id': 1,
    'parent_id': None}
```

This should even work with multiple root nodes (there will be a dummy Node with the id `None` at the top though)

Answer (score 2):

This does not require recursion.

First create a dictionary of nodes, one for each item using `id` as the key, which includes an empty list of children.  Then you can scan that dictionary, and add each node to the list of children for its parent (skipping those whose parent is `None`).  Once this scan is complete, every node that isn't a root will be in the child list of its parent, and thus all trees will be complete.

The roots of the forrest are the nodes that have `None` for a parent.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Hunter for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot quite grasp your answer. Could you please help to elaborate for me to understand it better? Because according to your answer, the child node could still be in the result as father node, but at first level I only need the father of each tree. My sample input has only one father node but actually there can be more than one with `parent_id : None`

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer but could I have a code snippet? I've been struggling with this for few hours. Based on your answer, I could not make a level 3 or higher. They all fall in level 2. Thank you.